# Why is UIActivityViewController not showing expected share options?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

`UIActivityViewController` largely works as expected in my app. I can generally exclude activities and provide the desired data, whether string or pdf. One bit still befuddles me. When I include the `PDF` option along with `String`, as shown below (#1), `Print` is an option, but `Add to Notes` and `Add to iCloud Drive` are not. When I do not provide a PDF option (#2), `Print` does not appear, but `Add to Notes` and `Add to iCloud Drive` do appear (and work). So the question is, what am I doing wrong that doesn't allow `Add to Notes` to appear when I provide both String *and* PDF?

Thank you!

## 1

```
    var objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [myString(), myPDF()]
    
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

## 2

```
    var objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [myString()]
    
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

**Edit**: In searching and reading, came upon a blog post from the folks at Tubmlr that, if I understand, says that a share extension will appear in the UIActivityViewController iff the share extension supports ALL the activity items made available by the app. That is, my app provides String and PDF, and I've figured that some extensions would take the text (Notes?), some would handle PDF (Print), and some might do both (Mail? Messages?). Seems I'm wrong. When I finally built a legit share extension (that handles just text), it behaved like Notes and only appeared if the activity item was only String. Does anyone have a strategy for this? If I don't put out a PDF, I lose Print; if I do, then I lose Notes and others. That doesn't yet make sense to me.

**Edit**: In researching the share extension, found more stuff to read, seeing a variety of comments on this topic. And different strategies and attempted mechanisms to overcome the perceived limitations. Pages takes the approach of asking the user for the preferred type of data (RTF, Pages, PDF, Word, etc). With just Text and PDF, gotta weigh the benefits of having the best and most robust extensions for the user vs the nuisance of imposing interface between the user and the controller.